# Sorting files 'numerically' instead of alphabetically in java

Tags: java

I have a folder with files which are named after timestamps.

When I try to go through each file it sorts them alphabetically and gives me this order:

```
/home/user/buffereddata/1
/home/user/buffereddata/100
/home/user/buffereddata/1000
/home/user/buffereddata/200
/home/user/buffereddata/2000
/home/user/buffereddata/300
```

But I want them sorted like this:

```
/home/user/buffereddata/1
/home/user/buffereddata/100
/home/user/buffereddata/200
/home/user/buffereddata/300
/home/user/buffereddata/1000
/home/user/buffereddata/2000
```

This is my code:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/buffereddata");

if(file.exists()) {
  File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();
  Arrays.sort(fileArray);
  for(File f : fileArray) {
    System.out.println(f);
  }
}
```

Is there some (preferably simple) way to loop through the files in the way that I want to loop through them?

Comment: You can parse the string for integer, then put both strings and parsed ints in two equally indiced arrays then sort the int array as doing same swaps for the string array. Maybe you need to write sorting method on your  own. You can make a hash table too, an int for a key and a string for it.

Comment: You should write a `Comparator<File>` which is based on the filename and sorts them numerically.

Comment: you can create a comparator see (http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) and do either a numeric compare (or pad the names with zero's to ensure they are of the same length and do a string compare)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort on a string that may contain a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)  (Not exactly, but close enough that the solutions are analogous.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(fileArray, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        try {
            int i1 = Integer.parseInt(f1.getName());
            int i2 = Integer.parseInt(f2.getName());
            return i1 - i2;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try it out. Should I catch my NumberFormatExceptions in the comparator or outside?

Comment: What about NumberFormatExceptions?

Comment: You should check NFE if you *expect* an NFE. If it should not happen, you would just throw an `AssertionError` either way (and embedding NFE). That's why NFE is a `RuntimeExcpetion` btw.

Comment: `try { return ...; } catch (NFE e) { return f1.getName().compareTo(...); }` (Fallback on string compare.)

Comment: What if filename has a separate two integers maybe for a folder name?

Comment: I editted your answer to something more complete because your initial code worked after I fixed the syntax and added the exception handling. Now I can select this as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually, the NFE **will not** be raised for `Arrays.sort()`. You can only handle it within compare.

Comment: I'd recommend NOT to throw any Error, as it usually will bypass your Exception handling. Consider throwing some RuntimeException!

Comment: @LastFreeNickname Yeah, it's rather religious question :-) In this particular example it is just a **demo** how may one handle NFE (makes more sense than rethrowing e).

Comment: @rlegendi: Don't want to start a discussion, but Errors are commonly reserved to be used by the JVM and should not be thrown by programmers. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813614/what-is-difference-between-errors-and-exceptions).

Comment: @LastFreeNickname In principle that's true. However, the `assert()` statement itself is throwing an error (specifically: an `AssertionError`). So basically if you know that control flow should not reach a certain point (i.e., place a control flow invariant), you cannot do anything else than throwing an `AE` explicitly. The reason is that you *must* return a value from the code (e.g., the `compare()` method here -- `assert()` statements are usually disabled). See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#usage-invariants). And as I stated, this is only a snippet.

Comment: So in a few cases it is reasonable to throw errors explicitly.

Comment: It is a valuable answer for me

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers are correct in your *specific case* (where all file names in a given directory are numeric only), here's a solution that can compare mixed numeric / non-numeric file names, e.g. `version-1.10.3.txt` in an intuitive way, similar to the way Windows Explorer does it:

[image]

The idea ([which I have blogged about here](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/23/how-to-order-file-names-semantically-in-java/). [The idea was inspired by this answer here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37217/5314).) is to split a file name into numeric / non-numeric segments and then compare each individual segment from the two file names either numerically (if both are numeric), or alpha-numerically otherwise:

```
public final class FilenameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private static final Pattern NUMBERS = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
    @Override public final int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Optional "NULLS LAST" semantics:
        if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
            return o1 == null ? o2 == null ? 0 : -1 : 1;

        // Splitting both input strings by the above patterns
        String[] split1 = NUMBERS.split(o1);
        String[] split2 = NUMBERS.split(o2);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(split1.length, split2.length); i++) {
            char c1 = split1[i].charAt(0);
            char c2 = split2[i].charAt(0);
            int cmp = 0;

            // If both segments start with a digit, sort them numerically using 
            // BigInteger to stay safe
            if (c1 >= '0' && c1 <= '9' && c2 >= 0 && c2 <= '9')
                cmp = new BigInteger(split1[i]).compareTo(new BigInteger(split2[i]));

            // If we haven't sorted numerically before, or if numeric sorting yielded 
            // equality (e.g 007 and 7) then sort lexicographically
            if (cmp == 0)
                cmp = split1[i].compareTo(split2[i]);

            // Abort once some prefix has unequal ordering
            if (cmp != 0)
                return cmp;
        }

        // If we reach this, then both strings have equally ordered prefixes, but 
        // maybe one string is longer than the other (i.e. has more segments)
        return split1.length - split2.length;
    }
}
```

You can then use the comparator as such:

```
Arrays.sort(fileArray, Comparators.comparing(File::getName, new FilenameComparator()));
```

Answer (score 3):

you need a custom comparator

```
    Arrays.sort(fileArray, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(f1.getName());
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(f1.getName());
            return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
        }});
```

Answer (score -1):

Basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8107018/1273830):

You can define your own comparator with compare function as:

```
public class FileSizeComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    public int compare( File a, File b ) {
        String aName = a.getName();
        String bName = b.getName();
        // make both strings equal size by padding 0s to the smaller one
        // then compare the strings
        return aName.compareTo(bName); // dictionary order!
    }
}
```

`compareTo` is a `String` class method which works to your benefit here.

```
"0100".compareTo("1000"); // < 0
"0100".compareTo("0200"); // < 0
"0200".compareTo("1000"); // < 0
```

So if you have 100, 200, 1000 you get 100, 200, 1000 and not 100, 1000, 200!

Should work, not tested!

Comment: No, this is wrong. `"200".compareTo("1000")` returns 1, not -1 as you suggest. String.compareTo() does alphabetical, not numerical comparison.

Comment: Also, FileSizeComparator is a misleading class name for your comparator.

Comment: Oh man! you are right! I was wrong. I had completely different notion about the string compareTo function in mind :( it's been long since I used java.

Comment: Yes. You should edit your answer, or delete it (there are two correct answers already); otherwise I'll have to downvote. :)